# why isn't my touch move delegate working?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios4

The first time `UITouch` begin and `UITouch` moved resulted in the delegate getting called correctly. But after adding a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the view only `UITouch` begin is called but `UITouch` moved is not called.

Comment: Sourcecode or it never happened. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add "gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;" to continue receiving touch events on your view.